# Enabling filestream with WMI and C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, wmi

I have need to enable FILESTREAM on a SQL Server through a program.  According to documentation I have found, this can be done through WMI with the following code:

```
set fsInstance = GetObject("WINMGMTS:\\" & MachineName & "\root\Microsoft\SqlServer\ComputerManagement10:FilestreamSettings='" & InstanceName & "'")
Set method = fsInstance.Methods_("EnableFilestream")
Set inParam = method.inParameters.SpawnInstance_()
inParam.AccessLevel = TargetLevel
inParam.ShareName = ShareName
Set outParam = fsInstance.ExecMethod_("EnableFilestream", inParam)
```

Converting this to C#, I get the following:

```
ManagementClass mc = new ManagementClass(new ManagementScope(@"\\.\root\Microsoft\SqlServer\ComputerManagement10"), 
                new ManagementPath("FilestreamSettings"), 
                new ObjectGetOptions(new ManagementNamedValueCollection() {
                    {"InstanceName", "MSSQLSERVER"}
            }));
ManagementBaseObject inParams = mc.GetMethodParameters("EnableFilestream");
inParams["AccessLevel"] = 1;
inParams["ShareName"] = "ALLIANCE";
mc.InvokeMethod("EnableFilestream", inParams, null);
```

Whenever I try this, though, it throws an exception on InvokeMethod.  The message is "Invalid method parameter(s)".  I have attempted to remove the two lines where I set AccessLevel and ShareName and run it that way, but get the same exception.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I'd work on executing the first sample in its environment and tweak the parameters until it works. Then port it. Otherwise you will be chasing your tail unless you luck into the solution.

Comment: The sample works perfectly.